# Recover GPO Rights

Tags: networking, active-directory

I messed up at work today, and I've accidentally denied a group (I don't know which one) from read-level permissions.

I went to work on delegation for a user for a GPO, and I must have accidentally clicked on either the Domain Admin or Domain User group and denied it.  But when I try to recover via DSACLS I get an error.

I can't seem to get ADSI Edit to fix it.  I'm logged in as a Domain Admin.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Edit: I made some headway but DSACLS gave me a "The command failed to complete successfully," error.

Edit #2: The account I'm using right now is a member of the standard Domain Admin and Domain User group.

Edit #3: Domain Admins are inaccessible for this GPO, too.

Comment: Can you include more details of what exactly you can't access? I'm guessing you removed your own admin account permissions and now you don't have the permissions necessary to add your own permissions back? Is there another domain admin account available to try? You could try building a new account that is **only** in domain admins and then is less likely to be in any group that has deny permissions on it.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've updated my question.

Comment: If you denied Domain Users, then all you need is an account that is in Domain Admins and not in Domain Users. If you denied Domain Admins, then things will be trickier. If you try to fix it with a Domain Admin that is not a Domain User, and you update the question with whether that worked or not, then you will either be fixed or we will know which group you denied and have a better idea of how to answer the question.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Domain Admins don't have access either.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've got it working now.

Comment: In case you don't already know, a great thing to do at this point is type up what you did that fixed it as an answer below and answer your own question. Then anyone else who has the same problem and searches here will find your answer.

Comment: @ThomasHutton  Could you put in what you did to fix the issue as an answer below?  Thanks.  Cheers, welcome to the site!

Comment: @ToddWilcox I updated with how I fixed it.

Comment: @Citizen I updated with how I fixed it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  Yes, but you updated it within the question.  If you could cut and paste what you did and use at as an answer to your question and mark it as answered this question can be considered closed in the system rather than open and still needing an answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @Citizen Done.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I've fixed it!* The I just (finally) found the GPO in question in ADSI Edit and removed the deny permission on Domain Admins... and BAM! It fixed it.

Comment: Go ahead and hit the checkmark to award yourself the answer.  +1

Comment: I can't for another 2 days.

Comment: ahh...that's right....

Comment: It would be useful to have the "GPO in question" you found in ADSI Edit listed here since its likely someone might not know what that is.